# Can I dynamically generate a python class on import?

Tags: python, dynamic, import, module, ondemand

I have a module, `foo`,  that dynamically generates a very large number of classes:

```
class BaseClass:
    pass

def make_class(n):
    class c(BaseClass):
        def __init__(self):
            print "I'm number {}".format(n)
    name = "class{}".format(n)
    globals()[name] = c
    c.__name__ = name

for i in range(0,1000):
    make_class(i)
```

I uses module by dynamically importing some of the classes:

```
for i in [1, 8, 9]:
    t = __import__("foo",globals(),locals(),fromlist=["class{}".format(i)])
    # use t
```

The problem is that loading `foo` takes a long time and, in practice, during one execution, I only need a few of the classes (but I don't know which until runtime).

Is there a way to dynamically create the class I need when I import it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the use case for this?

Comment: Couldn't you simply import your `make_class` function and generate only the classes you need ?

Comment: I would like the user of the code to be oblivious to the fact that this is going on.  I still want `from foo import x' to work as normal.